# Android MenuItem Custom Layout

Tags: android, layout, menuitem

I have a [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu) that appears when I click on an action button in a actionbar.
I would like the MenuItem, in my PopupMenu, with a custom layout like this:

layout/menu_item_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/menuItemLayout"

    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewMenuItem"
        android:layout_width="20dip"
        android:layout_height="20dip"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_list_focused_holo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewMenuItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextViewMenuItem" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the xml of PopUpMenu:

menu/pop_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       tools:context="apparound.actiobarpopupstylefacebook.Main" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/popupItem"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

In my activity code is following:

```
public void showPopup(int idR){
View menuItemView = findViewById(idR);
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, menuItemView);
MenuInflater inflate = popup.getMenuInflater();
inflate.inflate(R.menu.pop_menu, popup.getMenu());
MenuItem menuItem= popup.getMenu().findItem(R.id.popupItem);
menuItem.setActionView(R.layout.menu_item_layout);
popup.show();
}
```

But when appear popupmenu, item is empty. 
I was wrong to use setActionview() method?
Thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For custom layouts you can't use a menu, one alternate option is a [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html)

```
PopupWindow popupwindow_obj = popupDisplay();
popupwindow_obj.showAsDropDown(clickbtn, -40, 18); // where u want show on view click event popupwindow.showAsDropDown(view, x, y);

public PopupWindow popupDisplay() 
{ 

    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(this);

    // inflate your layout or dynamically add view
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);

    Button item = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
    popupWindow.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popupWindow.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popupWindow.setContentView(view);

    return popupWindow;
}
```

Create this XML file in the res/layout folder named my layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Window test" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: between 20+ question and answer , your answer is the best . you must give +500 or +1000 upvote .

Comment: There is dark border on popup window

Comment: Fixed with `popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(null);`

Comment: I don't understand this at all. Then why does PopupMenu even exist? If you can't use it for custom layouts, and you can only use it in the main layout, then why not just use ActionBar in main layout? I see no purpose to Popup Menu.

Comment: what is the point of     Button item = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
 I don't see it used anywhere.

Comment: How about clicking on Items? we should just set click listeners for them, like simple buttons, right? Any simpler ways?

Comment: Good day sir, just asking if how can I dismiss the Pop up window that I make. Because on other devices when I click outside the window the window itself did not close. But nice answer i upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

`Final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow();` // inflate your layout or dynamically add view

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_reply_chat,null); 
popupWindow.setFocusable(true); 
popupWindow.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
popupWindow.setHeight(180); popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(null); 
popupWindow.setClippingEnabled(false); popupWindow.setTouchable(true); 
popupWindow.setContentView(view); return popupWindow;
```

//above is working code i checked it

Answer (score 0):

By default the layout of a PopupMenu (and it's items) cannot be customized. In the solution below I have created a PopupMenu with a horizontal layout. In this case I used TextView as clickable items, but you can easily replace them by Buttons. You can customize the menu items whatever you want.

1 - The Custom PopupMenu class:

```
public class PopupMenuCustomLayout {
    private PopupMenuCustomOnClickListener onClickListener;
    private Context context;
    private PopupWindow popupWindow;
    private int rLayoutId;
    private View popupView;

    public PopupMenuCustomLayout(Context context, int rLayoutId, PopupMenuCustomOnClickListener onClickListener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.onClickListener = onClickListener;
        this.rLayoutId = rLayoutId;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        popupView = inflater.inflate(rLayoutId, null);
        int width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        int height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        boolean focusable = true;
        popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable);
        popupWindow.setElevation(10);

        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) popupView;
        for (int i = 0; i < linearLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View v = linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
            v.setOnClickListener( v1 -> { onClickListener.onClick( v1.getId()); popupWindow.dismiss(); });
        }
    }
    public void setAnimationStyle( int animationStyle) {
        popupWindow.setAnimationStyle(animationStyle);
    }
    public void show() {
        popupWindow.showAtLocation( popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    }

    public void show( View anchorView, int gravity, int offsetX, int offsetY) {
        popupWindow.showAsDropDown( anchorView, 0, -2 * (anchorView.getHeight()));
    }

    public interface PopupMenuCustomOnClickListener {
        public void onClick(int menuItemId);
    }
}
```

2 - Your custom layout, e.g. linearlayout with horizontal layout. In this case I use a simple LinearLayout with TextView items. You can use Buttons, etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/popup_menu_custom_item_a"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="A"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/popup_menu_custom_item_b"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:text="B"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />
    // ...
</LinearLayout>
```

3 - Using the Custom PopupMenu like the normal PopupMenu.

```
PopupMenuCustomLayout popupMenu = new PopupMenuCustomLayout(
        MainActivity.mainActivity, R.layout.popup_menu_custom_layout,
        new PopupMenuCustomLayout.PopupMenuCustomOnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(int itemId) {
                // log statement: "Clicked on: " + itemId
                switch (itemId) {
                    case R.id.popup_menu_custom_item_a:
                        // log statement: "Item A was clicked!"
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
// Method 1: popupMenu.show();
// Method 2: via an anchor view: 
popupMenu.show( anchorView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```