# Circular image in menu items and Android

Tags: android, menu, menuitem

I am working in sliding menu, in which I am putting my image and some texts. I want to give some properties in my menu items like my own text size, gravity, image in the center. My code is given below. It is not allowing me to put these properties in it.

My Menu Items XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_one"
        android:icon="@drawable/profileicon"
        android:title="Terms and Privacy">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_two"
        android:icon="@drawable/dentist"
        android:title="Settings">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_three"
        android:icon="@drawable/direction"
        android:title="Share">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_four"
        android:icon="@drawable/as"
        android:title="Contact Us">
    </item>

</menu>
```

My Main Activity XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.coboltforge.slidemenu.SlideMenu
        android:id="@+id/slideMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/menubutton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My code where I am giving header image:

```
    slidemenu = (SlideMenu) findViewById(R.id.slideMenu);
            slidemenu.init(this, R.menu.slide, this, 333);
            // this can set the menu to initially shown instead of hidden
    //      slidemenu.setAsShown(); 
            // set optional header image
            // this demonstrates how to dynamically add menu items
            SlideMenuItem item = new SlideMenuItem();
            item.id = MYITEMID;
            item.icon = myDrawable;
            item.label = "Dynamically added item";
            slidemenu.addMenuItem(item);
            myDrawable = mImageProfile.getDrawable();
            slidemenu.setHeaderImage(myDrawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you can customize the default menu. Instead you can use customized `PopUpMenu` with you own `layout` using this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23539930/1364896).

For the circular ImageView, you have to use an external library for that. Personally, I use this [library](https://github.com/Pkmmte/CircularImageView) for the Circular `ImageView`s

Answer (score 0):

the best way is ti use listView instead iff buttons ...
create a custom listView item 
create your baseAdapter that match your item
and then everything will be ok ,just adding item to list and updating it