# ImageButton does not display menu items when pressing it

Tags: android

I have a custom ListView. Inside the layout of the custom ListView, I have an ImageButton which acts as an overflow menu (similar to how the Menu on the ActionBar works):

layout/item_list.xml

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_more_vert_black_24dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/descr_overflow_button"
        android:id="@+id/overflowMenu"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
```

In the Activity, I configure this ImageButton as a Popup in the onCreate method:

```
    overflowMenu = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.overflowMenu);
    popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, overflowMenu);
    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
```

I also inflated it in onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = popupMenu.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popupMenu.getMenu());
    return true;
}
```

I have the following in menu/popup_menu.xml folder:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/report" android:title="Report"
          app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/share" android:title="Share"
          app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

And I added this:

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
    return true;
}
```

However, when I try to click on the ImageButton on the phone, nothing happens. It does not display the menu items as it should. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `PopupMenu` is exactly what you need . From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

> A popup menu displays a list of items in a vertical list that's
>   anchored to the view that invoked the menu. It's good for providing an
>   overflow of actions that relate to specific content or to provide
>   options for a second part of a command.

Now the reason why your implementation doesn't work is because `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onMenuItemClick` are for managing the menu for the **activity** so inflating the overflow menu there is pointless.

What you need to do is attach an `onClickListener` to your `ImageButton` and initialize the `PopupMenu` and call `show()` **inside your ListView/RecyclerView adapter**

```
imageButton = findViewById(R.id.overflow_menu);
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, imageButton);
MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        popup.show();
    }    
});
```

You can have a look at the docs linked above for examples as well.

Answer (score -1):

This Questions is duplication. 
For custom layouts you can't use a menu, you have to use to a PopupWindow

[Android MenuItem Custom Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23538929/android-menuitem-custom-layout)

```
PopupWindow popupwindow_obj = popupDisplay();
popupwindow_obj.showAsDropDown(clickbtn, -40, 18); // where u want show on view click event popupwindow.showAsDropDown(view, x, y);

public PopupWindow popupDisplay() 
{ 

    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(this);

    // inflate your layout or dynamically add view
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);

    Button item = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
    popupWindow.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popupWindow.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popupWindow.setContentView(view);

    return popupWindow;
}
```

// Create this XML file in the res/layout folder named my layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Window test" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sure about this? Then what is the purpose of PopupMenu?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23538929/android-menuitem-custom-layout

Comment: I don't understand this at all. Then why does PopupMenu even exist? If you can't use it for custom layouts, and you can only use it in the main layout, then why not just use ActionBar in main layout? I see no purpose to Popup Menu.

Comment: WHy would I put mylayout.xml in its on layout file? Remember this flyout menu is rendered for each list item in ListView.

Comment: If all this is is a basic popup, why not use DialogueBuilder?

Comment: @red_allocator please don't state incorrect information. The [Popup menu docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu) explicitly state that for list menu items `PopupMenu` has to be used while [PopupWindow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) is for displaying an **arbitrary view as a floating container**