# Inflating custom layout for pop up menu items

Tags: android, popup, menuitem, popupmenu

Is it possible to create custom layout for each pop up menu item in Android? I have inflated custom layout for list views but I am having some trouble with pop up menu items.

I have this piece of code (some lines that are not specific enough to this asked question have been removed).

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    View menu_hotlist;

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_alert, menu);
    menu_hotlist = menu.findItem(R.id.menuItem).getActionView();

    menu_hotlist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showProfileMenuPopup(v);
        }
    });
return true;
}

public void showProfileMenuPopup(View v) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(Home.this, v);

    for(int index = 0; index < list.size(); index++)
    {
        Menu menu = popup.getMenu();
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, index, index + 1, text);

        MenuItem item = menu.getItem(index);
        item.setActionView(R.layout.custom);

        TextView t1 = (TextView) item.getActionView().findViewById(R.id.textView);
        t1.setText(text);
    }

    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
            intent1.putExtra("key", value);
            startActivity(intent1);

            finish();
            return true;
        }
    });
    popup.show();
}
```

`item.setActionView(R.layout.custom)` does not seem to have any effect on inflating custom layout for pop up menu items, may be I did not use it properly or missed out some line of code? Please help out.

I have searched Stack Overflow but it discusses custom layout only for action bar menu items but not pop up menu items.

Asking question a bit earlier than required so that people will have sufficient time to answer it.

I am trying to get different background colours for pop up menu items which are in different groups but a specific order of items cannot be changed (as in e-mail). Is there a simple way to change background colours for pop up menu items?

- Using spannable string can format text inside of pop up menu items, but background colour changes only for text but not for entire pop up menu item.
- Using background colour in HTML mode text does not help out either.
- Using `ContextWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper(Activity.this, R.style.custom)` did not have any effect on the pop up menu items at all.
- Or is there any need to override `OnPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` function with some piece of code?

Please help me out to inflate custom layout on pop up menu items so that it would be useful enough in general (in the future).

There are of course other alternatives instead of using pop up menu items but they would not be impressive enough for my piece of work at all!

- Creating pop up dialog box with it inflating a custom layout. The pop up dialog box would get dismissed whenever clicking with the activity outside of it anywhere else but not just simply on the menu item in the action bar.
- Creating sub menu of pop up menu items those of which all ever would belong into a group that is different enough from the group of the other pop up menu items.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Never mind that the following question up asked up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23538929/android-menuitem-custom-layout?rq=1 within stack overflow I only got from 'Related' menu items into this question up asked up within stack overflow, but not by using a search engine seems to address into this issue.

Comment: Pop up window seems to be one single plausible alternative solution into this question up asked up within stack overflow. Is it really and then seriously possible to inflate within custom layout, if not at least change within background colour of into pop up menu item, if not for the text alone by using spannable string, but also into entire pop up menu item too?